# keepalived virtual and real server in different subnets

Tags: keepalived, keepalive

My goal is to forward the SMTP traffic from one unused server to another using keepalived.
The problem is, that the other SMTP server is in different subnet. I have configured keepalive in the following way.

```
virtual_server 192.168.111.111 25 {
        delay_loop 10
        lb_algo rr
        lb_kind DR
        protocol TCP

        real_server 192.168.222.222 25 {
                weight 1
                SMTP_CHECK {
                        connect_timeout 5
                        retry 3
                        delay_before_retry 5
                        helo_name "lb-lan-1.local"
                }
        }

        real_server 192.168.222.223 25 {
                weight 1
                SMTP_CHECK {
                        connect_timeout 5
                        retry 3
                        delay_before_retry 5
                        helo_name "lb-lan-1.local"
                }
        }
}
```

However, it seems that this setup does not work for some reason.
Is there a way to configure **virtual** and **real** IP in keepalive, but in different subnets?

Another workaround (i.e. OS settings) would be also considered as acceptable solution.